# Nested function manipulation in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to return the following code onto screen. Everything works fine except I cannot get the array being returned from the   JobDisplayFunction to be returned by its parent function and therefore into the render()

```
async renderJobs(){
  //do stuff
  this.apiclient.getJobsByEmployer('', async (error, returnVal) => {
    var job = returnVal
    console.log('job')
    console.log(job) //prints
    console.log('returnVal')
    console.log(returnVal) //prints
    jobDisplayFunction(job)
})

const jobDisplayFunction = function(job){
    var array = []
    job.forEach(function(result){
        console.log(result)
        if(result.active){
            array.push(
                <div className='sample'>
                    <Image src={profilePicture} height={50} width={50} alt='Employer Logo' rounded/>
                    <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                    <p>{result.location}</p>
                    <p>{result.sector}</p>
                    <p>{result.county + ', ' + result.country}</p>
                    <p>{'Paid: ' + result.compensation}</p>
                    <p>{'Total Applicants: ' + result.applicants}</p>
                    <p>{'Shortlisted: ' + result.shortlist}</p>
                    <p>{'Interviews: ' + result.interview}</p>
                    <p>{'Offered Job: ' + result.offer}</p>
                    <p>{'Accepted Job: ' + result.accepted}</p>
                    <p>{'Rejected Job: ' + result.rejected}</p>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.getJobIndex(result.active, result.id)}>duplicate</Button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }.bind(this))
    // return(array)
    return array
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `renderJobs()` being called? In a component?

Comment: Its being called inside the render() method like this: <div>{this.renderJobs()}</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so just incase anyone is ever planning on attempting something similar this is my advice:

**Step 1**: use the API call to set high level states in component did mount

```
var counter = 0
apicall.result.forEach(function(element){
    var name = 'jobNumber'+counter
    var holder = {name : element}
    for(key in holder){
        this.state[key] = holder[key]
    }
})
this.state.numberjobs = counter
this.setState(this.state)
```

**Step 2**: use states to populate fields in the render method as follows:

```
<div>{this.createDoms()}</div>
```

where createDoms() will cycle through the states set in the componentdidmount() like this:

```
createDoms(){
    var numberCurrentJobs = this.state.numberJobs
    var returnArray = []
    for(x in numberCurrentJobs){
        var array = this.state['jobNumber'+x]
        returnArray.push({array.title})//add all other DOM members
    }
    return returnArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when async functions are called it returns a Promise, either its a fulfilled Promise or a rejected Promise.

I suggest calling this.renderJobs() in componentDidMount() and set the data to your state and render the state in render(), could look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.renderJobs().then( (array) => {
    this.setState({ jobs: array });
  });
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.jobs) {
    return null;
  }

  return (<div>{this.state.jobs}</div>);
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.apiClient...().then( (returnVal) => {
    this.setState({ jobs: returnVal });
  });
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.jobs) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div>{this.jobDisplayFunction(this.state.jobs)}</div>;
}

jobDisplayFunction = (jobs) => {
  ...same as before
};
```

Comment: Doesnt this leave me with the same problem where renderJobs() isn't returning a value? Only the inner function is returning

Comment: what does console.log(this.renderJobs()) print if you place it in render() ?

Comment: No luck im afraid, it does throw an error or anything but still doesn't return anything from the outer function

Comment: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
undefined

Comment: ok so as you can see it returns a Promise. I suggest reading up on how Promises work and why we use them and on how async/await works with Promises. Also it looks like you might be missing some return statements aswell. return this.apiclient.. and inside that one return jobDisplayFunction(job)

Comment: I have promises in other places on the site and understand how they work, the question is about getting information from an inner function

Comment: Also, read this about what shouldn't go in state http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Comment: Yes you are right I did not actually look at what jobDisplayFunction did. But since your renderJobs is an async function this approach won't work since async functions always returns Promises. Maybe try to do you async call in componentDidMount() and pass the data to the renderJobs function and call it in render() ?